# Cannot create a file because of permissions

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to create a file in `sys/kernel/security` folder in Linux.

But `sudo touch test` returns permission error.

After `sudo chmod 777 /sys/kernel/security` it fails, so I tried to change permissions for `/sys` folder (yes, I know this is a bad way) and `sudo -i`. Files does not creates, but in all cases it sets correctly - drwxrwxrwx.

And now I actually have no ideas, so I hope to your tips.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`/sys/kernel/security` is Linux Kernel Security Module (LSM) space where kernel security module can show their data both r/w.

```
mount | grep security
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

This is another virtual file system mounted of `/sys`. You can't create files here and there is no meaning at all to create files here.

See, [securityfs](https://lwn.net/Articles/153366/) details here!